# Query set for a pie-chart

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I think I am just making a simple error here, but I can't seem to solve it. I am trying to create some fake data and analyze through different types of users which I will then put into a pie chart. Here is my models.py:

```py
from django.db import models

import factory
import factory.django
import factory.fuzzy
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import BaseProvider
import random


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    access_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
    session_duration = models.IntegerField(default = 0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                               MaxValueValidator(5)])
    traffic_source = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    created_account = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    paid_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, default = 'all_others')


class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    name = factory.Faker('name')
    address = factory.Faker('address')
    phone_number = factory.Faker('phone_number')
    access_date = factory.Faker('date')
    session_duration = factory.Faker('random_int')
    traffic_source = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(['Google', 'Facebook'])
    created_account = factory.Faker('pybool')
    paid_customer = factory.Faker('pybool')
    user_type = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(['registered', 'paid', 'all_others'])
```

And my `views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.db.models import Sum
from django.http import JsonResponse

from mysite.models import User


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def pie_chart(request):
    labels = [User.user_type]
    registered_user = User.objects.filter('registered')
    paid_user = User.objects.count('paid')
    all_others = User.objects.count('all_others')
    data = [registered_user, paid_user, all_others]

    #queryset = User.objects.order_by('-access_date')
    #for user in queryset:
        #labels.append(user.user_type)
        #data.append(user.user_count)

    return render(request, 'pie_chart.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

I am just getting into working with querysets so any help is much appreciated.

Edit: This is the error message I'm getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/ryan/All_Django/FinalProject/mysite/views.py", line 15, in pie_chart
registered_user = User.objects.filter('registered')
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1350, in add_q
clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1381, in _add_q
check_filterable=check_filterable,
File "/Users/ryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1247, in build_filter
arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /mysite/pie-chart/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @10 Rep, not sure if you changed anything? It doesn't look like it. Did you have any comments? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I fixed your formatting. It was indented by 4 spaces, and some people will downvote you for that. If you want to see exactly what I did, then click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62839405/revisions)

Comment: Plus, I know nothing about django. Sorry.

Comment: @10 Rep, ok, thanks. Didn't know that but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @rmoore35 you need to show the full error you are getting. Also which library are you using for charts?

Comment: @isAif, I've edited the original post for the full error message. I am using chartjs for my chart library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input everyone. I was able to solve it with the below changes to my views.py. Feel free to leave additional comments but I'll close it now.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.db.models import Sum
from django.http import JsonResponse

from mysite.models import User


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def pie_chart(request):

    queryset = User.objects.order_by('-access_date')

    total_registered = 0
    total_paid = 0
    total_others = 0

    labels = ['total_registered', 'total_paid', 'total_others']

    for user in queryset:

        if user.created_account == 1:
            total_registered = total_registered + 1

        elif user.paid_customer == 1:
            total_paid = total_paid + 1

        elif user.created_account == 0 and user.paid_customer == 0:
            total_others = total_others + 1


    data = [total_registered, total_paid, total_others]

    return render(request, 'pie_chart.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```